# Using two self-hosted Azure pipeline agents for artifact publishing in parallel mode

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I’ve got a build pipeline in Azure Pipelines containing several stages. The language – C#, .Net Core 3.1/.Net Framework 4.7 At the first stage of the pipeline, the whole solution is built, and unit and integration tests are run. At the next stages, different microservices and separate parts of the API are published and downloaded to Azure as separate artifacts. All this stuff is run on a self-hosted build agent.

I was trying to parallelize the stages after testing. The logic was that at these stages no build is done, only simple file copying and archiving are done. To do this, I ran two different build agents from the same pool on one computer. The agents were using the same local folder as their work folders. But when I tried to run the build pipeline, the agents started to compete for resources. The problem with the folder for build artifacts was solved, but it was not the only one. For example, both the agents were trying to create/delete the same temporary files in _temp folder. In this case, one task was failing with the following error:

```
[error]Unhandled: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'e:\_build\_temp\.taskkey'
```

Also, another type of strange errors started to occur. The text of the errors was something like on the screenshot below:
[A strange error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMBsY.png)

I guess, that conflicts between two agents caused these errors.

Using two different work folders for the agents seems not the best solution, because in this case, one agent will not have access to the files built on the first stage.

Does anybody have a successful experience in running two Azure Pipelines agents on the same machine for processing one pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel mentioned above you should not use the same local folder as work folders for your local agents

There are workarounds to share files between different stages on local machine agents.

For example, you can use [publish build artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) in stage A to publish the files that are needed in other stages to azure devops server. Then you can use [download build artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) in Stage B to download the files in its working directory.

**Update:**

Another workaround is to add a script task to [define a variable and set its value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) to the working directory of Stage A. And add dependency to Stage A in Stage B.

Then you can using expression `dependencies.<Previous stage name>.outputs['<name of the job which execute the task.setvariable >.TaskName.VariableName']` to get the value of the variable defined in Stage A, which is Stage A's working directory.

Please check below example: Stage B can access the working directory of Stage A and copy its files out to `c:\test\copyfromoriginalfolder`

```
stages: 
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: a
    pool: Default
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PathA]$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)"
      name: power1

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    PathInA: $[dependencies.A.outputs['a.power1.PathA']]
  jobs:
  - job: b
    pool: Default
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        cd $(PathInA)
        ls
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: $(PathInA)
        contents: '**'
        TargetFolder: 'c:\test\copyfromoriginalfolder'
        CleanTargetFolder: true
```

Hope above help!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @Levi-Lu-MSFT. The problem is that the solution is quite huge and has a complex structure of internal dependencies. It contains more than 60 projects, and its total size after all the projects have been compiled is about 2 GBs. So any try to copy the whole solution will become a time-consuming task, and copying different pieces of the compiled solution is an equivalent of ```dotnet publish --no-build```, so in fact, the publish task will be executed twice.

Comment: Hi @OleksiiSerik I tested on my local machine, and found agent could access the files built on the first stage. You only need to let the other stages know the path of the files/folders. I updated above answer. Please check it out.

Comment: @LeviLuMSFT Maybe, I've done something wrong, but the code example from your post does not work for me. Simply, try to set to the output variable any other predefined variable or a custom path, e.g. c:\temp or $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory). You will see that 'ls' still output the content of $(system.defaultworkingdirectory). Seems, the problem is that users can pass variables only between jobs and tasks, not stages. But anyway, your idea to share a path between two stages is great. I will try to move this way!

Comment: I found a way to share a custom value between two stages. Here is [an article](https://www.donovanbrown.com/post/Passing-variables-from-stage-to-stage-in-Azure-DevOps-release). And here is [MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/manage-database-changes-in-azure-pipelines/7-deploy-schema-change) where MS references the article.

Comment: That's great you work it out. You can post it as the answer.

Comment: UPDATE: In the beginning of May 2020, Microsoft added possibility to share output variables between stages in YAML pipelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages I did not try this feature yet, but anyway it sounds great, IMHO

Answer (score 0):

You can't and shouldn't do what you're trying to do. Agents intentionally run jobs in isolated, independent working folders. Trying to run multiple agents against the same working folder will cause race conditions and errors exactly like what you're seeing.